# Debugging a function in UFT

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I have written a code in UFT where i have a function which is written in other file, i have associated this function with "executefile" method . Now then I am trying to debug it control dosent goes inside the function. I want to debug inside the function and see how the code is working?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `ExecuteGlobal` to load a function library file into memory during a UFT run, you will not be able to step into it.

Open the function library in UFT, right click on its name tab and select "Associate with " to set up the association in UFT.  Once this is saved, you will be able to step into the function calls in the library using F11 at the relevant point instead of F10 (in Debug mode)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **`LoadFunctionLibrary`** to load your library at run time and you should be able to debug it using <kbd>F10</kbd> and <kbd>F11</kbd>.